# Check all checkbox from table header angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a table with first column as checkbox

```
<table *ngIf="Results && Results.length">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" name="all"  />
            </th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let Result of Results; let i = index">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="size1" value="{{Result.id}}" [checked]="Result.State" />
            </td>
            <td>{{Result.Column1}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I implement check All and uncheck all in Angular2 considering the fact that I have data coming from database in Result.State binding that the checkbox is checked or not. (this is working).
I need to check/uncheck if user enters manually and also if all the items returned from database are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create method in the typescript:

```
checkAll(){
   for(let i in this.results){
       this.results[i].State = true;
   }
}
```

And call it on click from somewhere, for the example:

```
<button (click)="checkAll()">Check all</button>
```